# Popover on top of Map Annotation bounces when changing orientation

Tags: ipad, ios5, uipopovercontroller, mkannotation, popover

in my iPad application I'm currently working, I have a map annotation and every time I tapped it, a popover is being shown to show its detailview. I have no problem on showing the popover. My problem is, when I tapped an annotation thereby a popover is being displayed on top it, and then changes my orientation, the popover bounces, meaning, it's no longer placed on top of its corresponding map annotation. Any ideas guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the popover's content view controller set up to handle all orientations?  Does it implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and/or shouldAutorotate/supportedInterfaceOrientations?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the comment, I was able to resolved this by calling the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation  method in which I dismiss the popover first, then call is again.